# formulation of replacement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just read the following formulation of the Axiom of Replacement in lecture notes, and am confused.

"For all $x, v_1, v_2,...v_n$, if $F(v_1, v_2,...v_n, u, v)$ is functional, then there is a $y$ such that, for all $v$, $v$ is an element of $y$ if and only if there is a $u$ which is an element of $x$ such that $F(v_1, v_2,...v_n, u, v)$,

for every formula, $F(v_1, v_2,...v_n, u, v)$, such that none of $x, y, z$ occur as variables in $F$."

A few questions:

Where did $z$ come from (or is that a mistake)?

Kunen merely requires that that $y$ not occur free on $F$ (though he formulates the axiom differently).  Must it really be added that $y$ (and $z$, whatever that is, not occur free either)?

Finally, if "$F$" at the end shorthand for $F(v_1, v_2,...v_n, u, v)$?  If so, isn't the requirement that $x, y$ and $z$ not occur free in $F$ redundant, since its free variables are specified?

Comment: And then there is the formulation from Wikipedia which apparently requires that x be free in F:   \begin{align}
\forall w_1,\ldots,w_n \, \forall A \, ( [ \forall x \in A &\, \exists ! y \, \phi(x, y, w_1, \ldots, w_n, A) ] \\
&\Rightarrow \exists B \, \forall y \, [y \in B \Leftrightarrow \exists x \in A \, \phi(x, y, w_1, \ldots, w_n, A) ] )
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, $z$ is irrelevant, there's no $z$ anywhere in sight. Kunen's assumption is fine; it's a simplifying assumption to require that neither $x$ nor $y$ occur at all in $F$. You may assume that $F$ at the end is shorthand for $F(v_1, ... v_n, u,v)$. It could very well have free variables only amongst those shown but also have bound occurrences of $x$ or $y$, if that weren't explicitly prohibited. Both definitions work.

Comment: Thank you!  Why would it matter if x or y occur as bound variables in F?

Comment: Really it wouldn't matter. I thnk it's just a simplifying assumption by the author of the notes — probably, maybe, it would simplify proving things by induction on complexity of $F$. As any bound occurrences can always be renamed to use a fresh variable, the requirement is harmless but unnecessary.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome.